# Unable to Make Prometheus Read the web-config.yml for TLS Encryption (Error: unknown long flag '--web.config.file')

Tags: java, spring-boot, security, ssl, prometheus

I am following the [official documentation](https://prometheus.io/docs/guides/tls-encryption/) regarding the TLS encryption of Prometheus. My Spring Boot uses https endpoints and thus I want Prometheus to scrap them as is. I am following the instructions but I am having problem in configuring Prometheus to read my web-config.yml. Specifically the following command,

```
prometheus \
--config.file=/mnt/d/Projects/Msc-Thesis-Project/prometheus.yml \
--web.config.file=/mnt/d/Projects/Msc-Thesis-Project/web-config.yml \
--web.external-url=https://localhost:8443/
```

throws the following error,

> Error parsing commandline arguments: unknown long flag '--web.config.file'
> prometheus: error: unknown long flag '--web.config.file'

Does anyone had encountered the issue? Any advices?